# Update specific columns of rows in a group with last row in the group value

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sql-update

[image]

Consider, I have the following table structure and I would like to update few columns of all the rows in a group with the last row in the group values. The output should be something like:

[image]

So I basically updated the rows in the group based on `entry_id` column and updated the `line_number` and the `entered_by` for all the rows in the group to match the last row values.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below to get your results

```
        WITH data
         AS (SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE),
         d1
         AS (SELECT entry_id,
                    Max(line_number)
                      over(
                        PARTITION BY entry_id
                        ORDER BY entry_id) line_number,
                    detailed_comment,
                    account_id
             FROM   data)
    SELECT d1.entry_id,
           d1.line_number,
           data.entered_by entered_by,
           d1.detailed_comment,
           d1.account_id
    FROM   d1,
           data
    WHERE  d1.entry_id = data.entry_id
           AND d1.line_number = data.line_number;
```

First take backup of the table using `create test_backup as select * from test` and then run the below MERGE statement

```
        MERGE INTO TEST s
    USING (
    SELECT distinct entry_id,
                        Max(line_number)
                          over(
                            PARTITION BY entry_id
                            ORDER BY entry_id) line_number,
                        detailed_comment,
                        account_id
                 FROM   TEST
    ) t
    ON (t.entry_id = s.entry_id )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET s.entered_by= decode(s.line_number,t.line_number,s.entered_by,null),
    s.line_number=t.line_number
```

AND second run the below MERGE statement

```
        MERGE INTO TEST s
    USING (
    SELECT distinct entry_id, Max(entered_by)
                          over(
                            PARTITION BY entry_id
                            ORDER BY entry_id) entered_by,
                        detailed_comment,
                        account_id
                 FROM   TEST
    ) t
    ON (t.entry_id = s.entry_id)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET s.entered_by=t.entered_by;
```

and `COMMIT;`

Comment: the merge is throwing an error in postgres. also, can we have one consolidate merge query to update all rows?

Comment: take backup into temp table delete from main_table and then insert from temp table to main table using my query

Comment: but if there are millions of rows, wouldn't this affect the performance badly?

Comment: you can use merge but two merge  are required tell me the error in postgres will try to fix

Comment: seems like the merge is not supported in postgres 10.12? I am trying it with INSERT..ON CONFLICT UPDATE